# How do I do error handling for failes RestAPI calls? I want to display the error instead of getting Code 500 Errors (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, rest, woocommerce

My webapplication requests content from a WooCommerce Shop via it's Rest API. The user is meant to set custom filters (e.g. order status). However, failed Rest API calls, due to e.g. bad parameteres or the shop not being available, result in HTTP 500 Errors. Instead I want to try the API call and display the errormessages to the user.

I tried wrapping the request in a try catch block, but the application crashes way before that.

Example code:

```
    public static function getOrders($key, $secret, $url, $status = "processing"){
        $woocommerce = WCApi::getClient($key, $secret, $url);
        $response  = "";
        try {
            // This line causes the error
            $response = $status == "all" ? $woocommerce->get('orders') : $woocommerce->get('orders', ['status' => $status]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response = $e;
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

When a status is requested that does not exist, I get a

> Error: Invalid parameter(s): status [rest_invalid_param]

error. This is the stacktrace with the WCApi class being the class containing my function from above:
[Screenshot of the stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DrOU.png)

Comment: You are just returning the `Exception` instance, try `$response->getMessage();` instead.

Comment: Don't paste screenshots of the errors, but the actual text. Next: open your laravel.log, find the error and copy/paste it in your original question. You want to stacktrace the error to where it started, hopefully in 1 of your functions which makes it easier to debug

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code, you are already catching the exception using a try-catch block. However, you are assigning the exception object itself to the $response variable, which may not be the desired behavior. To display the error message instead of the exception object, you can modify your code as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

public static function getOrders($key, $secret, $url, $status = "processing") { $woocommerce = WCApi::getClient($key, $secret, $url);
try {
    // Make the API call
    $response = $status == "all" ? $woocommerce->get('orders') : $woocommerce->get('orders', ['status' => $status]);

    // Process the response
    // ...

    return $response;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Log the error
    Log::error($e->getMessage());

    // Display a custom error message
    $errorMessage = 'An error occurred while retrieving orders. Please try again later.';
    return response()->json(['error' => $errorMessage], Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
}
```

In the updated code:

If the API call is successful, the response is returned as-is.
If an exception occurs, it is caught, logged using Laravel's Log facade, and a JSON response with a custom error message and a status code of 500 (HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) is returned.
Make sure to import the necessary classes and adjust the response handling based on your requirements.

Comment: Several of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).